# Routine for Division

Tags: c, recursion, gnu, division

I have been trying to do a simple division with integers. Using a series of subtractions and also trying to use recursion. Just imagine using a computer that can only use addition and subtraction. I have created a multiplication and a exponential, but I am having the hardest time with division. Any help or advice will go a long way!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int DIV(int m, int n){
    if(m == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else if( n == 1){
        return m;
    }
    else if(m > 0 && n > 0)
        return  DIV(m, n-1) - m;
} //exit
```

That is my code so far, just need help on the ending statement. Also `int m` is the numerator and the `n` is the denominator. I'm using GNU C by the way.

Comment: And the problem is...? Crash? Wrong result? ...? If latter, show some value examples. And "GNU C" isn't a language.

Comment: Technically, 0/0 is still undefined, this isn't part of the question but you should move your second if before your first if, the answer is always undefined if the denominator is 0.

Comment: what do you want to return if it is not divisible? like it has a decimal part. Also, maybe subtracting m from n and counting how many times did you subtract till you reached zero would be the only way if you are not allowed to use except addition and subtraction

Comment: No return value with negative `m,n`

Comment: According to this code, div(5,3) = div(5,2)-5; I'm thinking that's at least part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
else if (m < n)
    return 0;
else
    return 1 + DIV (m-n, n);
```

But if you want this code to actually run on a machine with limited resources, you should implement it as a while loop. Perhaps (error checking and negative number handling omitted):

```
int div (int num, int den)
{
    int ret = 0;
    while (num > den)
    {
        num -= den;
        ret++;
    }
    return ret;
}
```